# Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function when invoke createStore

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I was runnig a react-app and using react-redux to manage my state. It works well at first, But it crashed suddenly.I can't createStore any longer.It just told me "Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function"

I tried to re-install a low version react-redux as others told, but it doesn't work.
I cleared the cookies, restart the project, and nothing changed.
I just try the code as the example provided by redux offical size, and it sucks in the first step, which invoke createStore(reducer).

the dependencies version:

```
"react": "^16.9.0",  
"react-dom": "^16.9.0",  
"react-redux": "^7.1.1",  
"react-scripts": "3.1.1",  
"redux": "^4.0.4"
```

the index.js

```
import React,{ createStore }  from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'

import App from './App'
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker'
import reducer from './reducer'

const store = createStore(reducer)

// ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
render (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
 ,

  // document.querySelector('#root')
  document.getElementById('root')
)

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

and reducer.js

```
export default  (state , action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'INCREASE_COUNTER': 
            return {
                ...state,
                counter: state.counter + 1
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

I just wanted the app render successfully, it works fine before the problem occured. But I did nothing it just crash,and createStore didn't work any longer. It's really weird.

Comment: `import { createStore } from 'redux'`

Comment: Yep! I found it, o(╯□╰)o

Comment: Let's close this as a typo.

Answer (score 0):

It is a type error, fixed by:

```
import {createStore} from 'redux'
```

not from react